# Java script files are not loading with IP address (angular js with mvc + bundling)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, bundling-and-minification

We have created angular js application with MVC (js files bundling).
Site is working fine with server name (https://servername/site). 
But if we open the site with IP address (https://192.168.23.45/site), it is not working(js files are downloading but not showing in debugger in IE browser).

In local system it's working fine with IP address.

Any one facing same issue.

Any IIS setting need to be done to fix this issue.

Comment: SSL certificate issues? Take a look in the browsers developer menu and check the resources.

Comment: I am facing issue with IE 11 browser. Where I can find the resource menu in developer menu?

Comment: It's called Network - it lists all the resources that the webpage requests

Comment: ok, In network panel showing all js files are downloading.  But these are not showing in debugger panel.